# Install armadillo with clang instead of gcc

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, homebrew, armadillo

I'm using OS X 10.11.3. When I want to install armadillo library using brew with the following command: `brew install armadillo` it wants me to also install gcc:

```
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/armadillo: gcc, veclibfort, superlu43
==> Installing homebrew/science/armadillo dependency: gcc
```

Though, I don't want gcc. I'd like to compile necessary code using clang that is already on my computer. I tried setting CC, CXX, etc variables accordingly:

```
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
```

But it looks like brew doesn't want to use clang and it insists on gcc. What's more, in the [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/armadillo.rb) there is no explicit dependence on gcc.
How may I install required package without installing gcc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `armadillo` itself doesn’t depend on gcc, some of its dependencies do:

```
$ brew deps armadillo --tree
homebrew/science/armadillo (required dependencies)
├── cmake
│   └── sphinx-doc
├── arpack
│   ├── :gcc
│   └── :open-mpi
│   └── veclibfort
│       └── :gcc
└── superlu43
    └── :gcc
    └── veclibfort
        └── :gcc
```

`arpack`, `superlu43` and `veclibfort` need `gcc` to compile Fortran code.